# How can we say that Servet Belongs to Presentation tier than that of Business tier?

Tags: servlets

I have seen that Servlet belongs to presentation tier, Chech Link below
[Can anybody explain these words.Presentation Tier .Business Tier .Integration Tier in java EE with example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113818/can-anybody-explain-these-words-presentation-tier-business-tier-integration-ti)

Answer (score 0):

Because Servlets also contribute towards creation of web pages dynamically.
A JSP component which is also a type of Java servlet that is designed to fulfill the role of a user interface for a Java web application.The JSP engine loads the JSP page from disk and converts it into a servlet content. Just that Web developers write JSPs as text files that combine HTML or XHTML code, XML elements, and embedded JSP actions and commands.